# Flex 4 and Large XML files

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex4, large-files

Does anyone have experience with working with large local XML files?
Let's say 100.000 lines.

How feasible is it to do that with Flex 4.5 running on AIR?

Thank you.

Comment: haven't worked with xml files this big...but I was wondering...do you need to access all the data at once ? Maybe you can have a layer between your massive xml and your flex app that manages the data in the backend and returns only the required data for display (paginates the xml for flex)

Comment: That's wise advice, but there is no backend. The app is using this as a local storage file. I think the XML file comes from a long time ago, when SQLite didn't exist.

Comment: George, out of curiosity, how large was the biggest XML file? If you don't remember number of lines, filesize and do you remember how the performance was?

Comment: You a basic test to see how Flash Player handles it, but in case it's not feasible, you can a tiny script that would parse/chop the xml (in something easy/light like Python) and run that via command line/native process from air, if that's the case. On the same note, you could write a a basic Python script that populates a SQLLite database.

Comment: I'll consider that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is it will work, in theory. But it will work very slow. e4x will traverse but there is nothing API wise that will tell you when an operation on the root's children will complete. It will give the impression that your app is hanging. There used to be a limitation of 4GB file reference size but I believe things have changed. I'm not sure if AIR is attuned to the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit systems. In the case of 32-bit, there is 2GB limit that when broken a flash.errors.MemoryError will be thrown by the runtime. 100,000 lines of XML is not too bad but it can get pretty bloated if there is all kinds of namespaces, massive text blobs and the opening/closing tags.

Comment: Thank you, Mark, that's encouraging.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need full-blown XML syntax for parsing your files, you might consider creating custom parser, sort of SAX instead of default DOM model. Open that file, read line by line and stream the info into SQLite (lots of inserts will be more or less fast for non-indexed table.) This will let you do the job in limited portions without GUI freeze (although it may be not important for one-time conversion.)